# Unable to display special characters like ć in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, decode

I'm trying to diplay UTF-8 characters like "\u0107" in Java but it displays "?" :

```
      System.out.println((char) Integer.parseInt("0107", 16));
```

This does not work in my Java local server and in the proxy servlet on the cloud. I mean I get ? but I should get ć. What should I do?

The line of code above is part of an unescape function that mirrors the unescape available in javascript.

Comment: You have not mentioned any configuration you've done. Java naturally will print the correct character given that code _unless your configuration changes the character coding_ in some way. Many times that is a POM not including the UTF-8 declaration.

Comment: I think it's your font. Works fine here.

Comment: 1. Just use `System.out.println("\u0107")` as the sample, you're overcomplicating things ;-) and 2. the thing about the servlet not producing the same output should probably not go into the same question, as it's a completely different set of issues (though related) to go through.

Comment: I have seen that if I code this:  System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_16.toString())); the output changes but it's still not correct. I think that I need to set the output to some charset in the java local application and in the servlet. Otherwise the output character is wrong. However I don't know the charset to use (UTF8 doesn't work)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I haven't done any configuration whatsoever, it's a plain java application running in Eclipse. Besides, I have same issues in the Servlet on the server

Comment: @marco_sap - The Java configuration is only one part of a big puzzle. The console you are using has a configuration, the OS has a configuration, the server has a configuration and these are all separate and distinct from Java, but have an influence over what is actually displayed in the console. Try this to confirm the character is correct: `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString("\u0107".codePointAt(0)));` it should return `107`

Comment: I agree with other, but I think the best way to debug it is to write the character to a file, and then read the file in a UTF-8 compatible editor. So you remove most of possible problems. It it works, so go for console setting, locales, fonts, etc. Else, it is something in your java settings (compiler options, etc.)